# Designing the primary key in associative table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, primary-key

Suppose I have an `artist` table like:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Coltrane |
| 2 | Springsteen |

and a `song` table like:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Singing in the rain |
| 2 | Mimosa |

Now an artist can write more than one song, and a song  can be written by more than one artist. We have a many-to-many relation. We need an associative table!

How to design the primary key of the associative table?

One way would be to define a composite key of the two foreign keys, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE artist_song_map(
artist_id INTEGER,
song_id INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(artist_id, song_id),
FOREIGN KEY(artist_id) REFERENCES artist(id),
FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES song(id)
)
```

Another way would be to have a synthetic primary key, and impose an unique constraint on the tuple of the two foreign keys:

```sql
CREATE TABLE artist_song_map(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
artist_id INTEGER,
song_id INTEGER,
UNIQUE(artist_id, song_id),
FOREIGN KEY(artist_id) REFERENCES artist(id),
FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES song(id)
)
```

Which design choice is better?

Comment: I prefer the latter, for the reason @Meyssam Toluie gave.  Based on what you said, you need two indexes, one for artist, song, and one for song, artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you define the table as [`WITHOUT ROWID`](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) both queries will create the same table.

The column `id` in your 2nd way adds nothing but an alias for the column [`rowid`](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) that will be created in any of the 2 ways.

Since this is a bridge table, you only need to define the combination of the columns `artist_id` and `song_id` as `UNIQUE`.

If you want to extend your design with other tables, like a `playlist` table, you will have to decide how it will be linked to the existing tables:

- If there is no `id` column in `artist_song_map` then you will link
  `playlist` to `song` and `artist`, just like you did with
  `artist_song_map`.
- If there is an `id` column in `artist_song_map` then you can link `playlist` directly to that `id`.

I suggest that you base your decision not only on these 3 tables (`song`, `artist` and `artist_song_map`), but also on the tables that you plan to add.

Answer (score 1):

Logically the both design is the same. But from administration aspect the identity design is more efficient. Less disk fragmentation and future redesign or maintenance will be easier.

Comment: What is the "identity design"?

Answer (score 0):

Bridge tables normally don't require a ID(auto_inCREMNT) to identify the rows.

The linking columns(foreign key) are the main point, as thea link artists to a 8or songs)

only when you need special attributes to that bridge or you want to reference a row of that bridge table and don't want to have ttwo linking columns, then you would use such an ID field, but as i said normally you never need it

Answer (score 0):

While, generally, the differences are minor, the composite/compound foreign key design sounds more natural. A separate primary key together with the associated index  take additional space in the database. Further, if you use a composite primary key, you can declare the table as WITHOUT ROWID. According to the official [docs](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), "**in some cases**, a WITHOUT ROWID table can use **about half** the amount of disk space and can operate **nearly twice as fast**".